# Invoke-ScriptBlock - Half way through my month of lunches and I can't seem to find any docs on this command. Is it real?

Tags: powershell

From the new PowerShell in a month of lunches.  I can't get this command to work or find docs on it.

> 13.6 Using Invoke-ScriptBlock for one-to-many remoting
> The next trick—and honestly, this is one of the coolest things in PowerShell—is to send a command to multiple remote computers at the same time. That’s right, full-scale distributed computing. Each computer will independently execute the command and send the results back to you. It’s all done with the Invoke-ScriptBlock cmdlet, and it’s called one-to-many, or 1:N, remoting.

Comment: _can't get this command to work_ what is the actual problem? what happens when you call it? Have you tried `Get-Help`?

Comment: `Invoke-ScriptBlock: The term 'Invoke-ScriptBlock' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed no `Invoke-ScriptBlock` in PowerShell. My best guess is that the author is referring to using the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet with its `ScriptBlock` parameter. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2#using-script-blocks) for Microsoft's docs on `Invoke-Command` + `-ScriptBlock`.

Comment: Ok, thank you!   I was going crazy trying to figure this out.  I did end up going the Invoke-Command + -ScriptBlock route but my brain kept thinking I must be missing something because it was right there in the most poplar book.